# Sumar ARRAY, pero solo 1 columna

Tags: php, array

```
$Array
(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nombre] => Producto 1
            [precio] => 10
        )
 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nombre] => Producto 2
            [precio] => 20
        )
)
```

Mi código:

```
$c=(array_sum(array_column($array,'precio')));
echo $c;
```

Output:  `0`

En mi caso querría que hiciera 10+20=30

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Voy a añadir mas información para que se entienda, igual el error no está en la propia suma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si partimos de que `$consulta` es una consulta que devuelve +35 columnas y una de ellas es 'IMPORTEDTO'. ¿ La sintaxis estaría bien? Dejándolo así cómo esta ahora mismo `$c` no devuelve ningún resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a sustituir las comas con puntos como ha dicho @masterguru y sigue dando como resultado `0`, así es como ha quedado el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi tu código me funciona bien. Revisa bien el valor de $array pues allí debes tener el fallo.

Comment: Buenos dias,
Si, use el Array ese de ejemplo, en mi caso mi array tiene mas de 35 posiciones, lo unico que queria era representar eso en pequeño, y que se viera que el array tiene mas de una posicion numerica.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Recuerda que el espacio de respuestas, es únicamente para las mismas, y que puedes agregar más información pulsando en editar sobre tu pregunta. Para familiarizarte con el sitio, puedes leer ["Cómo preguntar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona mejor todo.

Comment: ejem... creo que el problema es el oci_fetch_array, que saca solo el primer elemento en lugar de todos... tendrias que crear un solo array con todo ese $result siguiendo la sintaxis del while del ejemplo: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.oci-fetch-array-examples

Comment: Si pegas ese código como texto en lugar de imagen te podré contestar mejor... porque en caso contrario tengo que escribirlo a mano y soy perezoso :-)

Comment: Perdon, no te habia leido jaj, lo bueno es que ya esta dando resultado, ahora tengo que ver porq ha dejado de dar los demas resultados, supongo que es por usar : $row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
y esto : $row2 = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
En el mismo PHP haciendo referencia al mismo $result, se te ocurre alguna forma de arreglarlo rapido?

Comment: Comprueba mi ultima respuesta, alli lo ejecuto en un ciclo y lo meto todo en un solo array para que luego lo demas funcione bien

Comment: Vale, nada, solo tenia que crear otro result y hacer referencia a el :
 $result=oci_parse($conexion,$consultafid);
 oci_execute($result, OCI_DEFAULT);
 $result1=oci_parse($conexion,$consultafid);
 oci_execute($result1, OCI_DEFAULT);

Comment: Entiendo que te ha funcionado mi respuesta al aceptarla, ¿cierto?  ¿O has tenido que hacer algun retoque más que se me haya escapado?

Comment: Ya funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!, no lo habria sacado sin tu ayuda, (estoy en practicas en una empresa despues del grado superior y los PHP los tengo atravesados jasjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Respuesta actualizada

Esta respuesta encaja mejor con tus últimas actualizaciones:

```
$result = oci_parse($conexion, $consulta);
oci_execute($result);

$array = [];
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

function decimal_coma_punto($itemarray) {
    $itemarray["IMPORTEDTO"] = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $itemarray["IMPORTEDTO"])));
    return $itemarray;
}

$array = array_map("decimal_coma_punto", $array);
$c = array_sum(array_column($array, 'precio'));
echo $c;
```

En esta respuesta, en lugar de tener un array de ejemplo como en la anterior, lo creamos mediante una consulta SQL a la base de datos recorriendo todas las filas para crear el array a procesar después.

### Respuesta original

El problema que tienes es debido a que los valores de precio, tal como has dicho después, son decimales con comas, cuando PHP espera decimales con notación de punto.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer esto:

```
$array = [
    [
        "id"    => 1,
        "nombre"=> "Producto 1",
        "precio"=> "10,2"
    ],
    [
        "id"    => 2,
        "nombre"=> "Producto 2",
        "precio"=> "20,5"
    ]
];

function decimal_coma_punto($itemarray) {
    $itemarray["precio"] = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $itemarray["precio"])));    
    return $itemarray;
}

$array = array_map("decimal_coma_punto", $array);
$c = array_sum(array_column($array, 'precio'));
echo $c;
```

**Output: 30.7**

**donde:**

- Definimos una función `decimal_coma_punto` que va a recibir los elementos del array uno por uno y va a modificar su columna `precio` modificando su notación de coma, para los decimales, por notación de punto, devolviendo de nuevo todo el elemento modificado.
- Efectuamos un [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) del $array para que envie todos sus elementos, uno a uno, a dicha función para realizar esa modificación, y lo asignamos de nuevo a la variable $array.
- Después ya podemos efectuar correctamente la suma esperada.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, si necesitas alguna otra informacion dime, gracias.